# Android change color in settings menu popup

Tags: android, colors, dialog, android-edittext, preference

I want to change the Text color of the inputfield in a preferencescreen. The defaul Text color is set to white, but you almost can't See white Text in a white Dialog so I want to change that. Ho can that be done? Also I want to change the checkbox Norder when the checkbox is not checked

Comment: find that `EditText`, then `editText.setTextColor()`

Comment: But it is not a normal edittext, it is a edittext in a Dialog in a preferencescreen

Comment: please give us your code to help you more